# Showing a div element dependent on if it has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

With jQuery I am trying to determine whether or not `<div>` has content in it or, if it does then I want do nothing, but if doesn't then I want to add `display:none` to it or `.hide()`. Below is what I have come up with,

`if ($('#left-content:contains("")').length <= 0) {
            $("#left-content").css({'display':'none'});
        }`

This does not work at all, if the div has not content then it just shows up anyway, can any offer any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [:empty filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty) in your selectors.

```
$('#left-content:empty').hide();
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly if there are whitespace textnodes inside `#left-content`. Eg `<div id="left-content">    </div>` (that's `"    "` inside an otherwise empty div.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation notes that it's only considered empty if there is no children, including text nodes.  That can definitely trip you up.

Answer (score 4):

```
if( $( "#left-content" ).html().length == 0 ) {
    $( "#left-content" ).hide();
}
```

Comment: In what case will `html().length` be LESS than 0?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove first whitespaces:

```
  // first remove whitespaces

  // html objects content version:
  var content = $.trim($("#left-content).html()).length;

  if(content == 0) {
     $("#left-content).hide();
  }

  // html RAW content version:
  var content = $.trim($("#left-content).html()); // <-- same but without length

  if(content == "") {                             // <-- this == ""
     $("#left-content).hide();
  }
```